# I can not select the right div using ".child" or ".next" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicking on the red circle, I only want the selected `<div>` element to move down, as it is now, all `<div>` elements are moving down because I don't point which `<div>` to move.

I have tried "child" and "this" but I can't get it to work properly.

```js
 var text = $('.text-overflow'),
   btn = $('.btn-overflow'),
   h = text[0].scrollHeight;

 if (h > 120) {
   btn.addClass('less');
   btn.css('display', 'block');
 }

 btn.click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();

   if (btn.hasClass('less')) {
     btn.removeClass('less');
     btn.addClass('more');
     btn.html('<i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

     text.animate({
       'height': h
     });
   } else {
     btn.addClass('less');
     btn.removeClass('more');
     btn.html('<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
     text.animate({
       'height': '73px'
     });
   }
 });
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.4;
  font: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #f7f7fa;
  color: #353535;
  margin-bottom: 383px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
section#head-nav {
  background: #202b35;
}
section#second-nav {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background: #f1f1f4;
}
.company-container {
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.company-container IMG {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.company-container span {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #959595;
}
.company-logo-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.company-logo-container IMG {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.company-container h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.company-container h5 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #a1a1a1;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
.glyphicon {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings' !important;
  // more css comes along here

}
.text-overflow {
  height: 73px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
a.btn-overflow {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #949494;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin-bottom: 03px;
  background-color: #ec2127;
  z-index: 999999 !important;
}
.company-container span.time {
  padding: 6px 9px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.open {
  color: #a1c988 !important;
}
.closed {
  color: #d89191 !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Restauranger</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">

          <img src="img/restaurang.jpg">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img src="https://ocast.com/upload/l-0wt4X9t7Zu6Lie_100x100.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>Krikelin & Co</h2>
          <i class="fa fa-circle open" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="time">11.00 - 14.00</span>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Hitta hit</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">
          <img src="img/restaurang2.png">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img src="http://www.lunchguide.nu/img/logo/ostersund/restauranghov.png?v=1442815946">
          </div>
          <h2>Restaurang Hov</h2>
          <i class="fa fa-circle closed" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="time">Stängt</span>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Karta</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">
          <img src="img/restaurang.jpg">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img src="https://ocast.com/upload/l-0wt4X9t7Zu6Lie_100x100.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>Krikelin & Co</h2>
          <i class="fa fa-circle closed" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="time">Stängt</span>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Karta</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">
          <img src="img/restaurang3.jpg">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img height="85" src="http://previews.123rf.com/images/tribalium123/tribalium1231210/tribalium123121000041/15575599-crossed-fork-and-spoon-food-icon-food-symbol-restaurant-label--Stock-Photo.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>Krikelin & Co</h2>
          <i class="fa fa-circle open" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="time">10:00 - 16:00</span>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Karta</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">
          <img src="img/restaurang.jpg">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/restaurangsymbol-med-kockhatten-38633339.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>Krikelin & Co</h2>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Karta</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">
          <img src="img/restaurang.jpg">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img src="https://ocast.com/upload/l-0wt4X9t7Zu6Lie_100x100.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>Krikelin & Co</h2>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Karta</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">
          <img src="img/restaurang.jpg">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img src="https://ocast.com/upload/l-0wt4X9t7Zu6Lie_100x100.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>Krikelin & Co</h2>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Karta</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="company-container">
          <img src="img/restaurang.jpg">
          <div class="company-logo-container">
            <img src="https://ocast.com/upload/l-0wt4X9t7Zu6Lie_100x100.jpg">
          </div>
          <h2>Krikelin & Co</h2>
          <div class="text-overflow">
            <h5 style="padding: 0px 10px;">
       <p>Dagens gourmetkorv med goda hemlagade tillbehör & riktig mos</p>
       <p>Stekt Bräckkorv från Undersåker med våran egna potatissallad</p>
       <p>Lchf-lunch är en stor salladstallrik med grillad gourmetkorv</p>
       <p>Cesarsallad med Svensk grillad kyckling, VB-ost romansallad</p>
      </h5>
          </div>
          <img src="img/gradient.png" style="margin-top: -15px;" height="20px;">
          <a class="btn-overflow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <div style="border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Karta</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style=" padding: 15px 0px;">
              <span>Matsedel</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27087/)

Comment: Please paste the required code here

Comment: And there is no red circle in the jsfiddle link you have mentioned!

Comment: Oh, sorry. Here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27087/

Comment: `text.animate({'height': '73px'});` is your only problem. You must use `$(this)` instead of `btn`

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27090/)

```
var text = $('.text-overflow'),
btn = $('.btn-overflow'),
h = text[0].scrollHeight; 

if(h > 120) {
    btn.addClass('less');
    btn.css('display', 'block');
}

btn.click(function(e) 
{
  e.stopPropagation();

  if ($(this).hasClass('less')) {
      $(this).removeClass('less');
      $(this).addClass('more');
      $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

      $(this).parent().find(".text-overflow").animate({'height': h});
  } else {
      $(this).addClass('less');
      $(this).removeClass('more');
      $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      $(this).parent().find(".text-overflow").animate({'height': '73px'});
  }
});
```